# A closed quotient map.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ a compact, Hausdorff space and $R$ an equivalence relation on $X$. Prove that if $R$ is closed in $X\times X$ then the quotient map $q$ is a closed map.

I like some advice. I have try some way and I get stuck.

I begun observing that $X/R$ is Hausdorff since $X$ is compact Hausdorff and $R$ is closed. Then I take a $F$ closed set in $X$, and consider the image $q(F)$. But I not sure what I should do from here.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.  The set $F$ is compact.

Comment: It looks like a trivial fact. :P 
Thanks!